# How to design sequential circuits using JK flipflops from output sequences of LED pairs?

Tags: led, digital-logic, flipflop

How do I solve problems like these where I'm given an output sequence of LED pairs and I have to design sequential circuits using JK flipflops? what should be my approach? where would I even begin?

[image]

Comment: State diagram, state transition table, excitation table for JK flip flops, required JK inputs in terms of Q1 and Q2 to have needed transitions.

Comment: For example, Q1(left LED) is SET on the next clock pulse if Q0 is 1 in the current time. So, you should utilize J-K inputs of the flip flop for Q1 in such way that they will perform SET action if Q0 is high, else no change or RESET. Use this kind of an approach to obtain Q0, then you have it completed.

Comment: It's just a twisted-ring Johnson counter. Look it up. [Really easy with two JK FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olYti.png). The general approaches have already been mentioned by @muyustan, though. I've written a lot about excitation tables and related approaches here, already, for example.

Comment: Useful search term for background reading : "Gray code counter"